# JLine example using multi word commands per line

Tags: java, command-line-interface, jline

I can't seem to find an example that uses more than one command per line.

For example, say I want to write a cli similar to cisco ios, where you may have multiple levels of commands on the one line.

eg. first word could be "show", then when you type "show " and hit tab, the next set of options are displayed (the cisco exmaple uses "?" to show the list).

```
eg:
gw1#show ?
  aaa                   Show AAA values
  access-expression     List access expression
  access-lists          List access lists
  accounting            Accounting data for active sessions
  adjacency             Adjacent nodes
  ..

gw1#show ip ?
  access-lists         List IP access lists
  accounting           The active IP accounting database
  admission            Network Admission Control information
  aliases              IP alias table
  arp                  IP ARP table
  ..

gw1#show ip interface ?
  ATM                 ATM interface
  Async               Async interface
  BVI                 Bridge-Group Virtual Interface
  CDMA-Ix             CDMA Ix interface
  ..

gw1#show ip interface
```

I'm thinking of using readCharacter to read one character at a time and then parse the line so far once I see a space.

Has anyone else had any Jline experience with this type of requirement?

Answer (score 7):

Using https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/master/src/test/java/jline/example/Example.java as reference, you might want to try the following. The key idea behind it is to use the `AggregateCompleter`class to do all the merging of the options for you.

```
List<Completer> completors = new LinkedList<Completer>();
                    completors.add(
                            new AggregateCompleter(
                                    new ArgumentCompleter(new StringsCompleter("show"), new NullCompleter()),
                                    new ArgumentCompleter(new StringsCompleter("show"), new StringsCompleter("aaa", "access-expression", "access-lists", "accounting", "adjancey"), new NullCompleter()),
                                    new ArgumentCompleter(new StringsCompleter("show"), new StringsCompleter("ip"), new StringsCompleter("access-lists", "accounting", "admission", "aliases", "arp"), new NullCompleter()),
                                    new ArgumentCompleter(new StringsCompleter("show"), new StringsCompleter("ip"), new StringsCompleter("interface"), new StringsCompleter("ATM", "Async", "BVI"), new NullCompleter())
                                    )
                            );
            for (Completer c : completors) {
                reader.addCompleter(c);
            }
```

After running the modified Example.java with the above, the output would look like the following.

```
prompt> show 
show    
prompt> show 
aaa                 access-expression   access-lists        accounting          adjancey            ip                  
prompt> show ip 
ip    
prompt> show ip 
access-lists   accounting     admission      aliases        arp            interface      
prompt> show ip interface 
ATM     Async   BVI     
prompt> show ip interface A
ATM     Async   
prompt> show ip interface A
ATM     Async   
prompt> show ip interface ATM 
======>"show ip interface ATM "
prompt>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using [AggregateCompleter](https://jline.github.io/jline2/apidocs/reference/jline/console/completer/AggregateCompleter.html) as shown below:

```
ConsoleReader reader = new MultiWordConsoleReader();
List<Completer> completers = new ArrayList<Completer>();

completors.add(new AggregateCompleter(new StringsCompleter("show"), new StringsCompleter("aaa", "access"), new NullCompleter()));
completors.add(new AggregateCompleter(new StringsCompleter("show"), new StringsCompleter("ip"), new StringsCompleter("accounting", "arp"), new NullCompleter()));

for (Completer c : completors) {
    reader.addCompleter(c);
}
```